# Routing for sessions#destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm linking to the destroy action for the Sessions controller like this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", session_path, method: :delete  %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Rails complains about the link above:

> No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"} missing required keys: [:id]

How do I link to the destroy action and keeping the REST/resource methodology in Rails when there's no object ID to provide for the link?

Comment: What prefix do you get for session when you do `rake routes`?

Comment: Then you must not show this link, when you don't have object ID

Comment: Sessions don't have IDs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is best to treat the routes to your sessions controller as a **singular resource**

routes.rb

```
resource :sessions
```

Doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

This will give you a route that you can use without ID's

DELETE  /sessions   sessions#destroy

Answer (score 5):

`destroy` is a member route, you need to pass `id` in the params to make it work, but you can do this to convert it to a collection route

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create] do
  delete :destroy, on: :collection
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

By default destroy method expects id, which should be pass with the link.
For Ex. you are destroying session for logged in user, then you have to pass `id` or `session` of logged-in user,
in this case, your link should be like this,
`<%= link_to "Sign out", session_path(user.id), method: :delete  %>`
or
if your purpose is to just delete/clear session only then you need to change in route.

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
delete '/session', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

If you want both types of link(In which we may pass ID or not), then you should try this route.
`delete '/session(/:id)', to: 'sessions#destroy'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the session resource to that route, like so:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", session_path(session), method: :delete  %>
```

Rails show and delete actions require a resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path, which in your case can be `/users/sign_out` or `sessions/sign_out` and not `/sessions` with a `DELETE` method.

Take a look at devise's [session destroy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L379) action and the route.

So, you could use something like

```
    resource :session do
      delete :destroy, path: 'sign_out', as: "destroy"
    end
```

Which will create path `/session/sign_out` which points to `sessions#destroy` and you can call it in your views as `destroy_session_path`.