# The action 'destroy' could not be found for ListingsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delete-method

**UPDATE - I'VE NOW SOLVED THIS PROBLEM** - I created a partial for the each Course item and rendered them from the main listing view. Thanks for all your help, I'm not really sure why it worked but it did **END OF UPDATE**

Apologies if this looks like a repeat posting but I've tried applying solutions to similar questions and they haven't worked, I'm stuck! Any suggestions welcomed, thank you.

**Problem**
I have a 'Courses' model which belongs to a 'Listings' model. The courses are created and deleted on a page belonging to Listing i.e. "/listing/2/courses"

**Error Message**

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/listings/2/courses"
```

**Courses Controller def destroy detail**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :set_listing
  before_action :set_course, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def destroy
    @course = @listing.courses.find(params[:id])
    @course.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Course deleted!"
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private

  def set_course
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  end

  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name, :curriculum_type, :summary, :address, :course_places, :start_date, :finish_date, :price)
  end

end
```

**listing/listingID/courses page detail**

```
<%= @listing.courses.each do |f| %>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <ul>
    <li>Name = <%= f.name %></li>
    <li>Type of course = <%= f.curriculum_type %></li>
    <li>Number of places = <%= f.course_places %></li>
    <li>Start Date = <%= f.start_date %></li>
    <li>Finish Date = <%= f.finish_date %></li>
    <li>Price (£) = <%= f.price %></li>
    <%= link_to "Delete Course", listing_courses_path(@listing, @course), method: :delete %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Routes.rb detail**

```
resources :users, only: [:show]
  resources :listings, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      get 'listing'
      get 'pricing'
      get 'description'
      get 'photo_upload'
      get 'amenities'
      get 'location'
      get 'courses'
    end
        resources :courses, except: [:edit] do
          member do
            get 'listing'
            get 'pricing'
            get 'description'
            get 'photo_upload'
            get 'amenities'
            get 'location'
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: check my solution

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of routes.rb?

Comment: @hoffm sure I've edited to include it above, thanks

Comment: I've now solved it, see top of page, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to listing_course_path(@listing,f), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

or try

```
  <%= link_to listing_course_path(@listing,id: f.try(:id)), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

route.rb

```
 resources :listings do
      resources :courses
 end
```

Comment: I've now solved it, see top of page, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

By default, `destroy` method expects an ID as it's a member route. You are using `listing/listingID/courses` route without an ID. For that you need to define `listing` and/or `courses` as singular resources ([read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)) like:

```
resource :courses do
:
end
```

as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830406/routing-for-sessionsdestroy-action) or make `destroy` a `collection` route like so:

```
resources :courses, except: [:edit] do
  delete :destroy, on: :collection
  :
  rest...
end
```

Try and see if this works.

By the way, this looks a bit redundant as you are iterating over each `@listing.courses` and calling `courses#destroy` where you are destroying all the `courses` of `@listing` anyhow. So, why do `@listing.courses.each` in the first place. You should have either used a `listing#destroy_courses` method or remove `@listing.courses.each` iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've changed it to: "resources :courses, except: [:edit] do
          delete: :destroy, on: :collection
          member do......." but I'm not sure of the syntax, its throwing the following error: "syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end delete: :destroy, on: :collection ^"

Comment: remove the ':' after delete.

Comment: I've now solved it, see top of page, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Update path in link_to to listing_course_path(@listing, @course) from listing_courses_path(@listing, @course)

```
<%= link_to "Delete Course", listing_course_path(@listing, f), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, now getting "Couldn't find Course with 'id'=2 [WHERE "courses"."listing_id" = $1]" and pointing to 1st line error in def destroy

Comment: I've now solved it, see top of page, thanks for your efforts